# Office Ribbon UI XML - How do you create an In-Ribbon gallery rather than a dropdown button?

Tags: ms-word, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, ribbon

I am trying to integrate a custom .net control into several Microsoft Office 2010 applications.

I have created my Ribbon UI in XML. But have no idea how to replicate an **In-Ribbon Gallery** control. (*such as the **Styles group** in Word, or the **Quick Steps** in Outlook*)

If there isn't a direct control that is available is there a way to approximate it with a different tag?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, using an In-Ribbon Gallery is not supported. The closest you can get is using the **[Gallery control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd548011%28v=office.12%29.aspx)** which displays a customizable dropdown grid - not an in-ribbon gallery:

```
<gallery id="galMonthsEng" label="Months (English)" 
    columns="3" rows="4"> 
    <item id="galMonth1" label="January"/> 
    <item id="galMonth2" label="February"/> 
    <item id="galMonth3" label="March"/> 
    <item id="galMonth4" label="April"/> 
    <item id="galMonth5" label="May"/> 
    <item id="galMonth6" label="June"/> 
    <item id="galMonth7" label="July"/> 
    <item id="galMonth8" label="August"/> 
    <item id="galMonth9" label="September"/> 
    <item id="galMonth10" label="October"/> 
    <item id="galMonth11" label="November"/> 
    <item id="galMonth12" label="December"/> 
    <button id="btnGal1" label="Regional Settings" 
        imageMso="ShowTimeZones" 
        onAction="ShowRegionalSettings"/>
</gallery>
```